# How to lock screen ratio? Unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started to develop a 2D platformer on Unity and I need the player to see only what falls in the 16:9 ratio, and the extra things are covered with black bars.

[Only what is in the white frame should be rendered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BTpY.png)

[But when building on my phone with a wide resolution, there is extra view on the sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAmeq.png)

To do this, I just made the usual black bars on the user interface, but is there a more practical solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because each phone have it's own resolution you need to write a script to handle those changes.

[You can look at this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=So-UJYoOPr8&ab_channel=RenaissanceCoders) for a already-written script and full explanation.

Comment: My problem is not with UI like in this video. I need the resolution of the game to be the same on any device (that is, where it exceeds the required values, black bars appear). But thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Setaspec : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera camera;
    public float width;
    public float height;
    public float zoom;

    private void Start() {
        camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        if (zoom > 0) {
            float scaling = (camera.orthographicSize*zoom);
            float fovScale = (camera.fieldOfView * zoom);

            camera.orthographicSize = scaling;
            camera.fieldOfView = fovScale;
            
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        camera.aspect = width/height;
    }
}
```

However this wont add black bars it will rescale the view instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).